# Unable to add a header section to UiCollectionView with xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

In a xib file, i've got a UiCollectionView. I would like to add a header to this UiCollectionView.

According to this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22) :

> Next, open up MainStoryboard.storyboard and click on the collection view inside of the Scene Inspector on the left (you might need to drill down a couple of levels from the main view first). Open up the Attributes Inspector and check the Section Header box under Accessories:
>
> If you look at the scene inspector on the left, a UICollectionReusableView has automatically been added under the Collection View.

I did it, but when I look at the screne inspector on the left, there is no a UICollectionReusableView.

[image: my UiCollectionView details]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I correct the problem:

Be sure your UICollectionView delegate is linked with File's owner in xCode.